# Need to install Go to use blogdown with Academic Hugo theme

Tags: r, go, blogdown

### Description

I wanted to set up a personal website with `blogdown`, using the [Academic](https://github.com/wowchemy/starter-academic) Hugo theme. I almost read the entire book of [blogdown: Creating Websites with R Markdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/) and several tutorials, like [Allison Hill's](https://alison.rbind.io/post/2017-06-12-up-and-running-with-blogdown/) or [Annie Lyu's](https://annielyu.com/2020/01/12/blogdown-website).

I have chosen blogdown because I am familiar with RStudio and R and Academic because there are suggestions in the references to pick a maintained theme, like Academic. I installed `blogdown` and Hugo as the book suggests and tried to install the theme by the RStudio way: click File -> New project -> New Directory -> Website using blogdown. If I tried the hugo-lithium theme, everything flows great. If I tried Academic, then the following message and error appeared (with some already installed files in the specified directory):

```
Congratulations! Your new Hugo site is created in C:\Users\HP\Documents\R\website.

Just a few more steps and you're ready to go:

1. Download a theme into the same-named folder.
   Choose a theme from https://themes.gohugo.io/ or
   create your own with the "hugo new theme <THEMENAME>" command.
2. Perhaps you want to add some content. You can add single files
   with "hugo new <SECTIONNAME>\<FILENAME>.<FORMAT>".
3. Start the built-in live server via "hugo server".

Visit https://gohugo.io/ for quickstart guide and full documentation.
trying URL 'https://github.com/wowchemy/starter-academic/archive/master.tar.gz'
Content length 133 bytes
downloaded 4.8 MB

Error: we found a go.mod file in your project, but you need to install Go to use it. See https://golang.org/dl/.: module "github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-modules/wowchemy" not found; either add it as a Hugo Module or store it in "C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\R\\website\\themes".: module does not exist
Error: we found a go.mod file in your project, but you need to install Go to use it. See https://golang.org/dl/.: module "github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-modules/wowchemy" not found; either add it as a Hugo Module or store it in "C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\R\\website\\themes".: module does not exist
Error: we found a go.mod file in your project, but you need to install Go to use it. See https://golang.org/dl/.: module "github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-modules/wowchemy" not found; either add it as a Hugo Module or store it in "C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\R\\website\\themes".: module does not exist
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"hugo" convert toYAML --unsafe' execution failed with error code 65535
In addition: Warning message:
In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
```

### Question

Do I need to install Go to use this theme? The *1.1 Installation* does not mention anything about Go (below section *2.1 Static sites and Hugo*, highlight by me), nor the tutorials. Is this connected with a release of the theme? Is the book outdated?

> We love Hugo for many reasons, but there are a few that stand out. Unlike other static site generators, the installation of Hugo is very simple because it provides a single executable **without dependencies** for most operating systems.

The `sessionInfo`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Hungarian_Hungary.1250  LC_CTYPE=Hungarian_Hungary.1250   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Hungarian_Hungary.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Hungarian_Hungary.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.0 bookdown_0.18  tools_4.0.0    blogdown_0.20  knitr_1.28    
[6] xfun_0.13
```

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [Edit your site on your PC](https://wowchemy.com/docs/install-locally/) docs on the Academic theme's webpage:

> Before downloading your site, lets first install Hugo Extended and its prerequisites.

On Windows: Git, OpenSSH and Go have to be installed beside Hugo Extended. Because I already have Git, I did not install it, only OpenSSH and Hugo Extended via Scope (and beforehand Powershell 5 to install Scope). Go was installed via the executable from [the Go documentaion site](https://golang.org/doc/install).

After this, Academic theme can be deployed with the RStudio method specified in the question. Maybe the blogdown book need to be updated.

Note: also, in the referenced document:

> **Convert an old Academic Kickstarter site**
> If you have an existing site based on the Academic Kickstarter Template that was created before *3rd September 2020*, it may need converting to use Hugo’s new modular system.

Comment: Note that you no longer need to install Go or GIT with the current development version of **blogdown** (which I plan to release to CRAN soon): `remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')`

Comment: Unfortunately blogdown::install_hugo() will not work sufficiently well on Windows, because it will not set the environment variables. It is important to install Hugo in a way that it is on th path.