# Blogdown new post addin creates but not loads new file

Tags: r, rstudio, blogdown

#### Context

After installed (see previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63898557/14261671)) and configured my personal Hugo [website](https://hermanp.github.io/en/) for a multilingual setup (by directories), I wanted to start creating content. Ideally, I wanted to use `blogdown` in RStudio, via the addins. The website uses the Academic theme, [rebranded](https://wowchemy.com/blog/introducing-wowchemy/) now as Wowchemy.

The content directory tree is as follows:

```
content
|
├── en
    ├── authors
    ├── files (for static files)
    ├── home (homepage widgets)
    ├── post
    ├── project
    └── resources
|
└── hu
    ├── authors
    ├── files (for static files)
    ├── home (homepage widgets)
    ├── post
    ├── project
    └── resources
```

**Multilingual** setup references:

- [Hugo Multilingual Part 1: Content translation](https://regisphilibert.com/blog/2018/08/hugo-multilingual-part-1-managing-content-translation/) - general overview, with managing content translations by directories and page bundles
- [Start a Multi Language Blog with Hugo on Github Pages](https://www.muscaestar.xyz/en/post/multilanguage-blog-hugo-github/) - for basic config.toml settings and highlighting the use of partials
- [Light/Dark/Automatic translation](https://github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-modules/discussions/1891) - for getting to know how to make modification in interface translations (although do not know how to share it with the themes repo)
- [How can I add credits by the end of the page?](https://github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-modules/discussions/1886) - for translating the footers of the webpages (which is not a content and can not be set in any config file), through partials.

#### Problem

When I use the new post addin in RStudio, the file is created in place, but does not open automatically for editing. The English and Hungarian language setting both works the same way.

[image: New Post addin settings]

```
> blogdown:::new_post_addin()

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6918
C:\Users\HP\Documents\R\website\content\en\post\2020-11-04-how-this-site-was-created\index.en.md created
Warning in file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'content/post/2020-11-04-how-this-site-was-created/index.en.md': No such file or directory
Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection
  91: file
  90: readLines
  87: hugo_convert_one
  86: new_content
  85: blogdown::new_post
  84: observeEventHandler
  13: shiny::runApp
  12: shiny::runGadget
  11: eval
  10: eval
   4: eval
   3: eval
   2: sys.source
   1: blogdown:::new_post_addin
```

#### Question

How can this be resolved? As far as I see, something has to be with the file path after creating the file, because the file is created in the right place.

#### Configuration

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Hungarian_Hungary.1250  LC_CTYPE=Hungarian_Hungary.1250   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Hungarian_Hungary.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Hungarian_Hungary.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.5.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5      bookdown_0.21   crayon_1.3.4    digest_0.6.26   later_1.1.0.1  
 [6] mime_0.9        R6_2.4.1        jsonlite_1.7.1  xtable_1.8-4    magrittr_1.5   
[11] evaluate_0.14   blogdown_0.21   rlang_0.4.8     rstudioapi_0.11 miniUI_0.1.1.1 
[16] promises_1.1.1  rmarkdown_2.4   tools_4.0.3     tinytex_0.26    fastmap_1.0.1  
[21] httpuv_1.5.4    xfun_0.18       yaml_2.2.1      compiler_4.0.3  htmltools_0.5.0
[26] knitr_1.30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not good at using the debug tools, so just stepped through the code. (Appreciate the suggestion of good tutorials!)

First things first: [When in Doubt, Try to Upgrade Your Software Packages](https://yihui.org/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/) This is the `blogdown` package creator's advice. Checked.

1. Launching the addin, `blogdown:::new_post_addin` is called.
2. This calls `new_post.R`. The source code can be find at: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/master/inst/scripts/new_post.R
3. `blogdown::new_post()` is [called](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/a555322e2ca1ec66ac37dd706720180284760210/inst/scripts/new_post.R#L90) at the end, with `file` parameter from the [updated](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/a555322e2ca1ec66ac37dd706720180284760210/inst/scripts/new_post.R#L73) input text field, which is in the case of the question: "post\2020-11-04-how-this-site-was-created\index.en.md"
4. `new_post()` function (in [hugo.R](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/a555322e2ca1ec66ac37dd706720180284760210/R/hugo.R#L434)) [calls](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/a555322e2ca1ec66ac37dd706720180284760210/R/hugo.R#L445) `new_content()` with the third argument, `open = FALSE`, which means it will not open the file, just overwrite the value of the `file` variable (the path hereafter). At the end of `new_post()` the file should be opened: this is where the error occurs (by trying to open the file at the wrong place, a wrong path). This means that something bad has to happen in `new_content()`.
5. `new_content()` [modify](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/a555322e2ca1ec66ac37dd706720180284760210/R/hugo.R#L350) the path with `content_file()`. Also this is the step, where the file is actually created.
6. `content_file()` [modify](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/a555322e2ca1ec66ac37dd706720180284760210/R/hugo.R#L397) the path by adding a prefix to it generated by `get_config()`.
7. `get_config()` tries to [extract](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/a555322e2ca1ec66ac37dd706720180284760210/R/utils.R#L570) the value of a field in the configuration, in the case of Hugo: try to find `contentDir`. If this results in NULL (there's no such list item), then see the other possibility and lastly return the default value (which is in the case of Hugo: `content`). And that's it! RStudio tries to open a file in the content directory, not in a language subdirectory!
8. That means that the last option is returned in the row of `%n%` (which is imported from knitr and stands for: `if (is.null(x)) y else x`). That means that the previous arguments returned NULL, which means contentDir cannot be found in `config` variable. The default value of `config` is set by `config = load_config()`. This uses `find_config()` to find the config file to parse.
9. `find_config()` [uses](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/a555322e2ca1ec66ac37dd706720180284760210/R/utils.R#L310) `config_files()` to set the value in case of Hugo: `c('config.toml', 'config.yaml')`. But my setting is in a subdirectory: in the `/config/default_/languages.toml` file! Oh, another Academic theme woe...

To conclude this: `blogdown` is currently loads only the `config.toml` in the root directory to check the `contentDir` value. The Academic, now Wowchemy Hugo theme however keep config files in the `/config/default_/` directory also, where the `languages.toml` contains the needed value.

*To keep or not to keep Academic theme?* *Stick with `blogdown` or not?* Maybe the config files should be merged into one config.toml, but couldn't find hint or examples for Academic on the web.

*Edit:* OK, the root of the problem has been found, but the actual error which raised the error message is in connection with `hugo_convert_one()`, as the traceback suggests in the question. This was the first (and last) try to open the file of the wrong path.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for the investigation! I'll look into it and hopefully fix it today.

Comment: FYI I've figured out the fix and will push it to Github later.

Comment: @YihuiXie Thank you so much for your work in blogdown and in this case also! Love your work and your blog! Useful info: I tried to move the English and Hungarian `contentDir` setting to `config.toml` with no avail. (Checked for the correct TOML syntax.) This would not have been optimal in the long run because of the fragmented language settings. Looking forward for the fix!

Comment: Could you try `remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')` and let me know if the problem has been fixed or not? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, the problem has been fixed by the [dc026f0](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/dc026f081f2ce9149f2b2f0b5e6f1c22b57d1e60) commit. However, if I create a post under `content/en/post/post1/index.en.md` and `content/hu/post/post1/index.hu.md` the files are linked. The [docs](https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/#translation-by-content-directory) says: _By having the same path and basename (relative to their language content directory), the content pieces are linked together as translated pages._ The basenames seem different, but it works.
Shall I mark this as accepted?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm not 100% sure what Hugo meant by "basename", but my guess is that the basename doesn't contain the language suffix (like `.en` or `.hu`), which is probably why it works for you. Anyway, of course, if it works, great! :)